# Entityform redirect from query

Tags: tokens

I am struggling to get the appended parameter from the url when redirecting an entityform.

I have an entityform that user can get to from multiple pages on the website. I want to redirect the user back to the page they came from versus just sending them to a generic landing page after filling out the form.

I can get the path into the url - `www.website.com/form-page/?source=page-I-came-from`
However, when I go to redirect them, What do I put into the redirect field so it redirects them to `www.website.com/page-I-came-from`

I have tried:
`%get[url]`
`%get[q]`
`[url:absolute]`
`[url:path]`

If I put `[current-page:url]` I get the entityform page url - How do I get the path from the url from the referring page to show up. I have tried many things and I am falling short.

I have not found anything that can help me to get this to work and I have spent hours trying.

Please does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: One thing. Usually in drupal if you want to specify a destination that you want to route the use you should use "destination" like ?destination=url-to-go-to

Often this will re-route you. Though I don't think I set up entityform to use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is a token `[current-page:query:?]` you just need to replace the ? with your query parameter, so `[current-page:query:source]` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I was looking for as a front-end UI person.

Answer (score 1):

From your example you can do something like this :

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'FORMID') {
    if (isset($_GET['souce'])) {
      $form_state['redirect'] = $base_url . '/' . $_GET['souce'];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So, with this I would create a small custom module with the above code?

Comment: you can do it in your template.php if you need to using `function <themename>_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)`

Comment: Thank you. I will try that out as well. I try not to get into too much code if I don't have too. I appreciate your response!